# How can I use an initialized model to use as a unique identifier for modal opening?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form, that has a `fields_for` with multiple records that are looped through.  Each record uses a modal that opens to then be used to add form entry.  My issue is that, in order to open the modal, I need to use unique identifiers.  Before the "main" forms record is created, I have no ID to use as a unique identifier.  I tried to use the initialized version, which is unique, but it will not open the model.  I assume because the initialized record has a `#` in it...

I have this working when a record is created, because then i can use the ID. But here is my issue for initialized records:

My controller:

```
@shop_product = ShopProduct.find_or_initialize_by()
```

Form summarized:

```
<%= form_for @shop_product do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>_<%= "#{@shop_product}" %>"  id="printLocationId_<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>(<%="#{ff.object.print_location.id}"%>)">
        Choose Image
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>_<%= "#{@shop_product}" %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false">
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Sync" %>
<% end %>
```

This translates to: http://jsfiddle.net/a01h6rz7

^This shows the relationship between the button and modal.  There are many of the modals so I need a unique one so the modal opens to the correct association.

When I have a record created, I can use `@shop_product.id` and it will work.  Is there any way to use `@shop_product` on a new to get a unique identifier that will work?

I am tagging javascript just in case there may be an idea or way to create a unique identifier based off of the `@shop_product` initialization.  If there is any more information you would like to help solve let me know

Comment: Aside from a way to create a unique id, I can only think of creating the record first before adding attributes to it and just setting a status to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<%= form_for @shop_product do |f| %>
    <% shop_product_id = @shop_product.object_id %>
    <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
        <% print_location_id = ff.object.print_location.id%>
    <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal-<%= print_location_id %>_<%= shop_product_id %>"
        id="printLocationId_<%= print_location_id %>(<%= print_location_id %>)"
    >
        Choose Image
    </button>
    <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="myModal-<%= print_location_id %>_<%= shop_product_id %>"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        data-keyboard="false">
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Sync" %>
<% end %>
```

1. First of all don't use `@shop_product` because thats an object. If you need a reference and it doesn't have an id yet, `object_id` will give you a unique identifier.
2. If you need to create/use the same thing again and again you can create a method in modal, or extract the value in a variable within the block.
3. If you don't need `print_location` then you don't need to do `ff.objec.print_location.id` which will query for `print_location`. Instead use `print_location_id`.
4. Don't use unnecessary string interpolation like this `<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>` instead just simple erb code such as `<%= ff.object.print_location.id %>`